# How to regex IMG where width >= 300?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

How can I get all of the `<img>`s with a `width >= 300`?

My markup/code:

```
$images = <<<END
<img src="/data/img/201108031_023" width="300" height="400" />
<img src="/data/img/201108031_026" width="250" height="300" />
<img src="/data/img/201108031_028" width="400" height="300" />
<img src="/data/img/201108031_032" width="500" height="400" />
...
END;
```

My attempt:

```
preg_match_all("/<img(.*?) \/>/",$images,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use regex for this.

This works for your specific example, but it has a number of problems because HTML can't be parsed correctly by a regular expression:

```
"/<img[^>]*width=\"([3-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]{3,})\"[^>]*>/"
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/G6IZ8)

I'd suggest you look for an HTML parser instead.

**Related**

- [Robust and Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)

Comment: If this were literally the only html to scan, wouldn't a parser be a bit heavy?

Comment: Ok, thanks mark, this is the best way for regex, and I will try to use html parser.

Answer (score 0):

```
"/<img[^>]*width=\"[0-9]*[3-9][0-9]{2}\"[^>]*\/>/"
```